# Identifying port numbers for ArcGIS Online Basemap?

Tags: arcgis-online, network, arcgis-online-basemaps

we have web map application on DMZ server, it was created by "ArcGIS API for JavaScript". our client needs to block all port numbers that access on Internet except URL of (arcgisonline rest services) for reasons related to Security Policy.

So is there any idea how to find port numbers or IP of [arcgisonline_basemap](https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services)

Comment: Is this application accessible in your browser? then it will require only port 80. If it is something else, then you'll have to ask the developers. Otherwise it's also possible to figure out by running a Network sniffer like wireshark.

Comment: the IP Server is local and the users also are local, the application need only to access arcgisonline basemap

Comment: then it would be port 80 & 443 if it is using https services

Comment: OK, thank you, i think also provide them port 80 & 443 with URL arcgisonline basemap, to filter access on internet based them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the official *[Domain Requirements for ArcGIS Online](http://downloads.esri.com/resources/enterprisegis/AGOL_Domain_Requirements.pdf)*. These can be used as general guidelines for what addresses need to be whitelisted. It really depends on what is being used in the application. If it uses, for example, basemaps, then https://*.arcgisonline.com needs to be whitelisted as basemaps typically come from the following address:

https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services

If the application also uses feature services, then you will also have to whitelist https://*.arcgis.com as they typically come from an address that looks like this:

https://services.arcgis.com/pMngm7HXxTrNXxGi/arcgis/rest/services

In terms of limiting based on IP addresses, this is not really possible as many ArcGIS Online systems do not utilize static IP addresses at this time (as outlined in the document).

In terms of ports, its all http or https traffic, which equates to ports 80 and 443.